# SQL Server Max memory setting not taking effect

Tags: sql-server, memory-usage

I am having trouble with restricting SQL Server 2008's memory usage on our Windows Server 2008 server.
The system has 11GB of RAM, I have tried restricting SQL's memory usage to 8.5GB by setting "Maximum server memory (in MB)" to 8500 but it is still currently using over 9.5GB of memory (even after a reboot).

Any ideas how to restrict it properly?

Thanks